# How to run .j filetype on a Linux machine?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

The title says everything else for itself. I've tried to execute this .j file for hours now.
As far as I understood it contains java byte-code, which can be executed by the Oracle Java Virtual Machine. But I can't find out how to call the Java Virtual Machine from the command line, or what I actually have to do.

I tried to call:

```
jvm imul.j
```

This didn't work.

The text editor can't see what the .j file actually contains.

P.S. I only used Linux a couple of times in my life.

Comment: Type in a terminal the command `file imul.j`: try also to run it using `java imul.j`; and install Linux on your laptop to learn it.

Comment: Neither of those worked, i looked into file and it doesnt have any main method so java imul.j will fail. file imul.j give this error: imul.j: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

Comment: The command `file` did tell (it is not an error!) you what is your file. So now, `unzip` it!

Comment: a bit stupid uestion, but how do i do it? unzip imul.j?

Comment: Yes, try `unzip imul.j` in a terminal

Comment: Archive:  imul.j
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of imul.j or
        imul.j.zip, and cannot find imul.j.ZIP, period.